# Xamarin Forms - How to deal against iOS includes of the PCL part

Tags: path, platform

It's hard to find a title for my problem but it simple to understand !

I have this following code which is a control (gif)

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
    public string GifSource
    {
        set
        {
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            string GifAssetURL;
            switch (Device.OS)
            {
                case TargetPlatform.Android:
                    GifAssetURL = "file:///android_asset/";
                    break;
                case TargetPlatform.iOS:
                    //GifAssetURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
                    GifAssetURL = "";
                    break;
                case TargetPlatform.Windows:
                    GifAssetURL = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/";
                    break;
                default:
                    GifAssetURL = "";
                    break;
            }

            html.Html = String.Format(@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' style='width:100%;height:100%;'/></body></html>", GifAssetURL + value);
            SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
            this.Margin = -10;
        }
    }
}
```

It works for every platform, however, when it's the time to generate a `release`, it throws an error about the include *(Android & UWP)*:

```
using Foundation;
```

However, I need this include for the iOS part because my **GIF Image** is located in a folder of the **Project.iOS** part..

**First, I use `NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath` but maybe, it could be a simple string?**

**Second, is it possible tooget a valid string path from a `ImageSource.FromResources("");`? In that case, I think it would solves the problem..**

Thank for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I then, finaly, found a solution !

So finaly, using the `Fondation` link is crashing my release compilation and the idea to get ride of it, is to have a `BaseUrl` interface, let me explain !

First, take back my gif object:

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
    public string GifSource
    {
        set
        {
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            // Take a look on this line !
            string GifAssetURL = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

            html.Html = String.Format(@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' style='width:100%;height:100%;'/></body></html>", GifAssetURL + value);
            SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
            this.Margin = -10;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the OS currently used, the good path will then be given.

So, to make it works, you have to create an Interface in the PCL Part like that:

```
namespace Project
{
    public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
}
```

Then, for each platform you're focusing, create a class which inherit from `IBaseUrl`. Take a look below: *Android, iOS & UWP*

### Android

```
using Project;
using Project.Android.DependencyService;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace Project.Android.DependencyService
{
    public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
}
```

### iOS

```
using Foundation;
using MapPinsProject.Interface;
using MapPinsProject.iOS.DependencyService;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_iOS))]
namespace MapPinsProject.iOS.DependencyService
{
    public class BaseUrl_iOS : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        }
    }
}
```

### UWP

```
using Project;
using Project.UWP.DependencyService;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_UWP))]
namespace Project.UWP.DependencyService
{
    public class BaseUrl_UWP : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ms-appx-web:///";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ! Have fun !